# EntityType has no key defined error, but I do have a key defined. Why is this failing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to write an object to a database and it's throwing the following exception:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> EntityType 'PageResponse' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType. PageResponse: EntityType:
>   EntitySet 'PageResponse' is based on type 'PageResponse' that has no
>   keys defined.

But I *do* have a key defined. Why is it still failing?

this is my code:

```
public class PageContext : DbContext
{
    public PageContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<PageResponse> PageResponse { get; set; }
}

[Table("PageResponse")]
public class PageResponse
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PageResponseId;

    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string OriginalUrl { get; set; }

    public Uri ResponseUri { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new PageContext())
{
    try
    {
        PageResponse pr = new PageResponse
        {
            Text = data.Text,
            Uri = data.Step.Uri,
            Title = data.Title,
            OriginalUrl = data.OriginalUrl,
            ResponseUri = data.ResponseUri,

        };

        db.PageResponse.Add(pr);
        db.SaveChanges();  

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    } 
}
```

Comment: No.. I didn't know it existed until you said something. Should I? Or should I be looking for something?

Comment: No, if it's any help, it's a console application.. I've only done anything EntityFramework in MVC applications.

Comment: well... full disclosure: this is part of the NCrawler solution (http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/). I'm trying to introduce Entity Framework to my local project to write some stuff to my local DB. But I don't think so. I just did a global search for "[Key]" and I didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Spotted it eventually, have cleaned up the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key property is not defined properly, it has no getter or setter. Change this:

```
public int PageResponseId;
```

To this:

```
public int PageResponseId { get; set; }
```

Comment: boom! that did it. I normally specify the getters & setters but didn't even notice they were missing this time! Nice one. I've moved on to a new error `Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry` but that's a different question for different day.